# php exec sudo -u root ... uses another username

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sudo, php-7.1

I'm positively stumped with a problem that escapes me entirely - and I can't seem to find any documentation specific to it.

I just recently switched to php7.1 to refactor a webapp that's been running for years on php5.3. In the old version I use things like

```
exec("sudo -u root -S some_command < /path/to/secret/password/file");
```

and it always ran flawlessly, **still does today**.
On the same server under a different domain with php7.1 I'm trying the same thing and I'm having no success.

```
exec("sudo -u root -S some_command 2>&1 < /path/to/secret/password/file", $output, $retval);
```

gives me an error message

```
["[sudo] password for otheruser:","Sorry, try again.","sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts"]
```

It apparently tries to use **otheruser** as the user **instead of root**! WHAT?!
Apache runs as www-data, otheruser (name changed) is something entirely different (an FTP user) and plays no role in that context.

sudoers file is the same for both domains/php-versions (if I'm not mistaken).

So it seems to come down to the difference in php-versions. Any insight might help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you absolutely positive, the user names, uid numbers, sudoers files, etc. are exactly the same? I'd try to run other commands, like `whoami`, `env` and `pwd` to try to trace down, what is the actual environment your `exec()` your commands in?

Comment: @Dan Yes, everything is the same / just exists once on that machine (sudoers, passwd, ...).
As a temporary workaround I now have included "otheruser" in the sudoers for use without password and now I don't even have to give a sudo username. It apparently always uses "otheruser" for i.e. `exec("sudo mkdir .....")`. This also seems odd to me.
One more thing I noticed: "otheruser" is the default systemuser for the domains in Plesk which I don't know how it got there. I don't log into Plesk with this one...

Comment: It sounds to me the two users might have the same uid? Try saying `id username` for both "otheruser" and the expected php user.

Comment: @Dan I think your thought goes in the right direction yet this isn't the case. root has ID 0, otheruser 10000... There still must be something that assumes otheruser instead of root. As I said before, it works great in Putty console but not via apache (running under www-data).